# Check if contains four digits year number in apple script

Tags: regex, applescript, contains

Now I am working on a `file-rename-applescript-project`. Here is an example: `The.Fantasy.1997.DVDRip.XviD-ETRG.avi`.

Now I want to check if the filename contains four digits year number. In this case, it's 1997. The year number MUST begin with 19 or 20 and MUST contain four digits.

If the result is true I will do something, if false I will do something else. 
I try to use regex but can't find the solution. It's out of my range. Now I m looking for help here, Thanks a million.

Comment: Let's say your file is named `TheFantasy1997.DVDRip.XviD-ETRG.avi` what should happen then? Should we consider `1997` as a year and within range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid regex completely, do something like below, using text item delimiters:

```
(*
    This first bit breaks the string up into a list of words by cutting the string 
    at the period delimiter.
*)
set tid to my text item delimiters
set my text item delimiters to "."
set bits_list to text items of file_name_string
set my text item delimiters to tid

(*
    This repeat loop goes though the list of words and tests them (first) to see 
    if it can be converted to an integer, and (second) whether the number is between
    1900 and 2100. If so, it chooses it as the year.
*)
repeat with this_item in bits_list
    try
        set possibleYear to this_item as integer
        if possibleYear ≥ 1900 and possibleYear < 2100 then
            -- do what you want with the year value here
            exit repeat
        end if
    end try
end repeat
```

Of course, this will not work properly if there's a number in the name (e.g., "2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.avi") or if a file name has different delimiters (e.g., a space or a dash). But you'd run into those problems using regex as well, so...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only wishing to check whether or the filename contains a four-digit year within the range 1900-2099, you can do this very simply by defining a handler like so:

```
on hasYearInTitle(filmTitle as text)
    repeat with yyyy from 1900 to 2099
        if yyyy is in the filmTitle then return true
    end repeat

    return false
end hasYearInTitle
```

Then you can call this handler and pass it a film title, like so:

```
hasYearInTitle("The.Fantasy.1997.DVDRip.XviD-ETRG.avi") --> true
hasYearInTitle("The.Fantasy.197.DVDRip.XviD-ETRG.avi") --> false
hasYearInTitle("2001.A.Space.Odyssey.1968.avi") --> true
hasYearInTitle("2001.A.Space.Odyssey.avi") --> true (hm...)
```

---

<sup>As a side-note, films indexed by *newznab* servers follow a strict file-naming protocol that allow a media server (on your machine) to parse it easily and extract information quickly, pertaining to (as seen in your example file name): the film's title, the film's release date, the source material, the encoding quality, the encoding format (codec), the release group, and the containing file format.</sup>

<sup>Although some filenames contain more information, and some they should always appear in an set order.  This makes them very simple to parse yourself should you need to, but if you're looking to create an organised media library, you would be best looking at using media server, of which there are excellent, freeware, long-standing software options available for macOS and pretty much any other operating system.</sup>

Comment: Double checked. It works for me. Thank you very much. I can only accept one answer. @Ted Wrigley 's answer is also right and earlier. And I find a way to put it in my Keyboard Maestro project. So I accept his answer. But your answer is also correct (and simpler). Thank you again!

Comment: OP says _"The year number MUST begin with 19 or 20 and MUST contain four digits"_. However, let's say we pass a filename of `Foo.Bar.11997.DVDRip.XviD-ETRG.avi` to the `hasYearInTitle` subroutine it returns `true`, i.e. it incorrectly considers `11997` to be within year range.

Comment: @RobC Thank you for catching that, and quite an obvious error for me not to have considered it.  Will update, but have a splitting headache right now, so my screen time is about to be forced to zero for a while.

Comment: @CJK - Get well soon! Author of OP must have a trustworthy and standardized filename convention in place, as they said it works for them - likewise for accepted answer. I went down the route of  shelling out to `grep` as per [this example](https://paste.ee/p/6SPZT). The `hasYearInRange` func determines if given filename includes an isolated group of 4 consecutive digits ranging from 1900 to 2099. It's not dependent on strict file-naming conventions. I really wanted to use a Perl regexp as it supports Negative Look(behind|ahead) which would have resulted in ....

Comment: @CJK - `set exitStatus to do shell script "grep -Pq '(?<![0-9])(19|20)[0-9][0-9](?![0-9])' <<<" & fileName & "; echo $?"` instead. in the gist provided at the previous link I had to mimic it using ERE and check length of matched string -  sadly `grep` on macOS no longer supports `-P` option `:(`

Answer (score 0):

The regex `.+\.(?:19:20)\d{2}\..+` should do it

The breakdown:

`.+` 1 or more any characters
`\.` An actual dot
`(?:19|20)` The string "19" or "20" (non-capturing group)
`\d{2}` Exactly two digits
`\.` An actual dot
`.+` 1 or more any characters

Comment: Thanks for reply. On https://regex101.com/r/1ZXb61/1 , (19|20)\d{2} works. But how to check if it exists? And how to put it in applescript?